# modX add og:image and og:description dynamically

Tags: facebook, share, modx

I am trying to create a Facebook share option for my blog articles, and it works but it doesn't take the article text or image, but the first image and text on the (single page) website. How can I change my share code so that it will use the article's image and text from where I click the FB share button?

This is the template for the blog article, with the FB share code included:

```
<div class="contentLeft">
   <div class="roundimage">
    <a href="[[+roundImage:phpthumbof=`h=750&zc=1`]]" class="colorbox" title="[[+roundImageCaption]]"><img class="round" 
    src="[[+roundImage:phpthumbof=`w=170&h=170&zc=1&q=95`]]" alt="[[+roundImageCaption]]" /></a>
   </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&amp;t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=[(site_url)][~[*id*]~]" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" class="fbsharebutton"></a>
        <h4 class="blue" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:0;">[[+articleHeadline]]</h4>
        <p class="datetext">[[+datetimeText]]</p>
        <p class="readmoretext">[[+articleText]]</p>
   <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

I hope you can help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to make sure that the article page, ie the link that you are sharing, embeds the correct og:image and og:description. You only share the link with the share button, and facebook will embed the link and look in it for the proper data.

**Update**:
I guess you're not using the articles package to create the blog? If you are you already have individual pages even if you're not using them =) If you're not i assume you're using some sort of resource loop to create your entries.

After looking around in the facebook docs it seems you can specify the image (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#params) when creating your share button using the javascript sdk (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). Each article will need to call something like this instead of the current javascript share url functionality.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.likes',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      image: "YourImageForThisRespectiveShare",
  })
}, function(response){});
```

If you prefer to explore the method i mentioned in the comments it would go something like this:

Look in your code at `u=location.href;`, you'd want to try modifying that to `u=location.href+'?articleid=[~[*id*]~]';`. When you share you should hopefully see the appended article ID for each article.

You'll then need to make sure you can specify og:image and description for each article, i assume you somehow have resources set up that represent each article, in that case just create a couple of template variables for that resource type.

In your header you could then use the `getResourceField` package for example to retrieve the correct TV from the correct resource, as specified by the `?articleid=` parameter in your URL.
To retrieve the parameter you'll need a simple snippet like `return (!empty($_GET['articleid']) ? $_GET['articleid'] : $default);`. Lets name the snippet: "getArticleId". I left the option to decide a default image when there is no &articleid specified.

You're using modx evolution from the look of your `[~[*id*]~]` tag, but there should be some equivalent of the getResourceField package for evolution. This is the revolution version of the code needed:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[[!getResourceField?
    &id=`[[!getArticleId? &default=`[[*id]]`]]` //Take the blog page's own image as a default
    &field=`imageTV` //you'll of course have to change "imageTV" to whatever you call it
    &isTV=`1`
]]" />
```

Repeat for og:title and og:description, with their respective TV names.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. How do I embed the og:image and og:description information within the link?

Comment: As i understand it you are trying to embed the image and description for each article in your list, directly in the link. But your facebook link only needs the URL as it already is. The URL links to the article's individual pages, not the article listing page. And the individual page can use the meta og:image and og:description tags.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have individual pages for the articles, and that's m problem........is there a way at all, to hand over those metas within the FB share link, or do I HAVE to find a way to make each article a separate page?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to send specific images with the actual link. What you share to FB is an actual page, from which it reads the og: tags. I would also say it's best practise for SEO purposes to have articles reachable through their own pages. If thats not an option, i guess you could try working around it by adding an `&articleId` parameter to the URL, and when you render the page you dynamically fill in the og: tags based on the article ID specified there. That way FB will recieve the right tags when it parses the link.

Comment: Thank you Kristian for explaining to me in depth, and I wish I had set up those articles as individual pages. I might have to redo it and do it this way, if I can't make it work as it is right now. However, I would like to try your other suggestion with the &articleId, could you explain a bit further how this could be done?

Comment: Thank you Kristian, I will try this and report back here if it works :)